# Why won't Windows hosts file block websites?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, hosts

I'm trying to block a website because someone keeps downloading crap from this website and it's spyware. I tell them it's spyware and they download it anyway.
So I'm trying to block it via the hosts file.

My host file looks like

```
127.0.0.1   scorpionsaver.com
127.0.0.1   174.129.20.145
```

the second entry is the actual IP address of the website.

I save the changes. I'm running it as an admin so it doesn't make me save the changes to a new file. It saves directly to the hosts file.
So I save and quit. Then I reboot my computer. 
I visit this website and it still loads.
So I also tried using 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1.
Same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

127.0.0.1 should be sufficient, as this will route any traffic to the loopback adapter.

To effectively block the site, use the full DNS name(s):

`127.0.0.1 scorpionsaver.com www.scorpionsaver.com subdomain1.scorpionsaver.com`

Verify that your changes persist after rebooting.